# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()'

Tags: android, google-play-services

2022-09-15 16:22:07.477 29909-29997/io.sendnow.sendnow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle
Process: io.sendnow.sendnow, PID: 29909
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()' on a null object reference

I am trying to get the most recent location and send it to my server, unfortunately the app crashes on the error shown above.

**MyFirebaseMessagingService class:**

```
package io.ionic.starter;

import android.Manifest;
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequest;
import androidx.work.WorkManager;
import androidx.work.Worker;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;
import io.sendnow.sendnow.MainActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


  private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
  private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

  private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

  private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this);
  }
```

(........)

```
  private void handleNow() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      // TODO: Consider calling
      //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
      // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
      //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
      //                                          int[] grantResults)
      // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
      // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
      return;
    }

    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
      .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
          // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
          if (location != null) {
            // Logic to handle location object

            boolean isCharging = MyFirebaseMessagingService.getCharging(getApplicationContext());
            float batteryLevel = MyFirebaseMessagingService.getBatteryLevel(getApplicationContext());

            String username = sharedPref.getString("sendnow_username", "nativestorage_null");
            String userId = sharedPref.getString("sendnow_user_id", "nativestorage_null");
            String licenseholderId = sharedPref.getString("sendnow_licenseholder_id", "nativestorage_null");

            String urlString = "URL"; // URL to call
            String params = "username=" + username + "&" + "user_id=" + userId + "&" + "licenseholder_id=" + licenseholderId +
              "&" + "altitude=" + location.getAltitude() + "&" + "speed=" + location.getSpeed() + "&" + "location=" +
              location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude() + "&" + "lastGpsUpdate=" + location.getTime() + "&" +
              "charging=" + isCharging + "&" + "batteryLevel=" + batteryLevel;
            OutputStream out = null;

            try {
              URL url = new URL(urlString);
              HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
              urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

              BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
              writer.write(params);
              writer.flush();
              writer.close();
              out.close();

              urlConnection.connect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
          }
        }
      });
  }

 
}
```

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.sendnow.sendnow"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 131
        versionName "1.20.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.1.0"
    force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0"
    force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
    force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:18.0.1"

    force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0"
    force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:18.0.1"
  }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'
  testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"

  // Import the Firebase BoM
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.2') {
    force = true;
  }

  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
  implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1"
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.8"


  // Add the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
}


apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'
```

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this);
  }
```

I moved it to the handleNow function so fusedLocationClient actually exists. I am a Java/Android developer noob so maybe this makes a lot of sense to other devs, but I hope I can help someone with this answer.

```
private void handleNow() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this);
```